# Sum two columns in a grouped data frame using shift()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I have a data frame `df` where I would like to create new column `ID` which is a diagonal combination of two other columns `ID1` & `ID2`.

This is the data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Employee':[5,5,5,20,20],
                   'Department':[4,4,4,6,6],
                   'ID':['AB','CD','EF','XY','AA'],
                   'ID2':['CD','EF','GH','AA','ZW']},)
```

This is how the initial data frame looks like:

```
  Employee  Department  ID1 ID2  
0         5           4  AB  CD   
1         5           4  CD  EF   
2         5           4  EF  GH       
3        20           6  XY  AA   
4        20           6  AA  ZW
```

If I group `df` by `Employee` & `Department`:

```
df2=df.groupby(["Employee","Department"])
```

I would have only two option of groups, groups containing two rows or groups containing three rows.

The column `ID` would be the sum of ID1 of the first row & ID2 of the next row & for the last row of the group, ID would take the value of the previous ID.

**Expected output:**

```
        Employee  Department ID1 ID2 ID  
    0         5           4  AB  CD  ABEF 
    1         5           4  CD  EF  CDGH 
    2         5           4  EF  GH  CDGH     
    3        20           6  XY  AA  XYZW 
    4        20           6  AA  ZW  XYZW
```

I thought about using `shift()`

```
df2["ID"]=df["ID1"]+df["ID2"].shift(-1)
```

But I could not quite figure it out. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
(df["ID1"] + df.groupby(["Employee", "Department"])["ID2"].shift(-1)).ffill()
```

almost your code, but we first groupby and then shift up. Lastly forward fill for those last rows per group.

```py
In [24]: df
Out[24]:
   Employee  Department ID1 ID2
0         5           4  AB  CD
1         5           4  CD  EF
2         5           4  EF  GH
3        20           6  XY  AA
4        20           6  AA  ZW

In [25]: df["ID"] = (df["ID1"] + df.groupby(["Employee", "Department"])["ID2"].shift(-1)).ffill()

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
   Employee  Department ID1 ID2    ID
0         5           4  AB  CD  ABEF
1         5           4  CD  EF  CDGH
2         5           4  EF  GH  CDGH
3        20           6  XY  AA  XYZW
4        20           6  AA  ZW  XYZW
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html), concatenate, and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
df['ID'] = (df['ID1']+df.groupby(['Employee', 'Department'])['ID2'].shift(-1)
           ).ffill()
```

output:

```
   Employee  Department ID1 ID2    ID
0         5           4  AB  CD  ABEF
1         5           4  CD  EF  CDGH
2         5           4  EF  GH  CDGH
3        20           6  XY  AA  XYZW
4        20           6  AA  ZW  XYZW
```